# How can I compare two sets of data having two columns in excel? Picture below will elaborate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Below are two sets of data. Each has two columns. I want that that the similar data comes in front of each other.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd suggest using `VLookUp`.  There are many examples online such as [this one](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-vba/).  Alternatively, you could try `Index`/`Match`.  Also check out the [tour] (earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].  More about what's on topic here is in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hi, asking for a ready solution to your problem is likely going to attract negative votes. Please edit your question, post code which you have already tried, and describe the issues you're having. Someone will surely help you resolve them. In the meanwhile, please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually i am not a programmer. I am a mechanical engineer and need help so that I do this work faster. The data i have shared above is just a sample. The real data has lots and lots of rows. I want to do it faster. I would appreciate if someone could help me out

Comment: Since I'm not asking you to come over to my place and build something, I humbly suggest you hire a programmer for now and enroll in a rudimentary Excel course sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual solution with formulas and sorting.

Imagine the following data in columns A to E:

[image]

Enter the following formulas into columns G to K

- Column G: `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D:D,A:B,2,FALSE)=E:E,1,2),3)`
- Column H: `=IF(G:G<3,D:D,"")`
- Column I: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H:H,A:B,2,FALSE),"")`
- Column J: `=D:D`
- Column K: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J:J,D:E,2,FALSE),"")`

The column G sort by now shows:

- `1` if part and quantity matched
- `2` if only part matched
- `3` if nothing matched

So if you now select data from A3:K10 and sort by column G (sort by) then it will result in this:

[image]

Comment: @SaadAhmed What is your question? This is already the explanation of how to do it. The main formula is the one in column G, that looks if the part and quantity exists in both data sets and rates it by 1, 2 or 3 as explained above. The other columns just pull the corresponding data with VLOOKUP.